# Creating a trigger to count the total price of a bill

Tags: sql, database, triggers, db2

I have these tables in my restaurant database:
PRODUCT, ORDER, AND BILL(you may find them in the attached picture)
i want to create a trigger to count the total amount of the bill(i can count it by selecting **sum(O_Quantity * P_Price)**).
Actually i want it after inserting the ORDER's data(the order table should be empty, but i entered some data to help in understanding the question)
I do appreciate your help 
thx 
[image]

Comment: Why store the data redundantly?  Just create a view with the appropriate query.

Comment: yeah you're right, but it's just that the trigger is one of the requirements i'v been asked to do in the project, and that's almost the only place i could implement it :)

Comment: The trigger you want is an update/insert/delete trigger(s) on the `order` table.  Each time one of the rows changes, you make an incremental change to the `bill` table.

Comment: but the problem is that the change in the bill table should be done after updating many records in the order table.

Comment: for example:
the **BILL_Total_Price** of **BILL_Num**:01 in the **BILL** table should be updated after inserting 9 rows in the **ORDER** table

Comment: If your trigger is designed to modify the `BILL` table after modification to the `ORDER` table, then you can get it to execute just once by performing that 9-row insert into the `ORDER` table within a transaction, I think.  Not a DB2 expert and just realized this was DB2.

Comment: ...you have pointed out that this is a good way to run into update errors of various sorts, right?  Additionally, depending on certain factors, this is a good way to lock the `Order` table (note, it's usually a good idea to avoid reserved/keywords for table/column names...); while the db is going to do it's best to keep lock sizes to a minimum, it retains the right to lock the _entire_ table under the right circumstances (it starts by upping to index/table pages first).  Note that I **would** have a `Bill` table, I just wouldn't auto-populate (used for "actual charge" record).

Comment: Which DB2 platform are you working with? DB2 for LUW (Linux,Unix,Windows), IBM i (f.k.a. OS/400), or z/OS?